# Inverse trigonometric functions which returns a complex output - depends on angular mode or not?

Tags: java, android, trigonometry, complex-numbers, radians

I am developing an Android app which need to calculate a trigonometric functions that supports complex numbers.

When the parameter of inverse trig functions is out range, the result should be a complex number.

My question is if the complex result should be converted to the current angular mode (like a Real number) or stay in radians.

For example:
asin(90) = 1.5707 - 1.0232i  (radians)

In DEG mode: Is the result should be: 90 - 297.5i ?

Thanks to all respondents!

Comment: This depends more on your need.

Comment: I think I looking for a standart like in scientific calculators. I've tested several scientific calculators and when the result is complex, some of them displays the results in radians even that the angular mode is in degrees.
I don't understand why they converts a Real result and Complex not...

Comment: Please elaborate more clear what your problem is. What do you expect? And what do you get instead? Please review our SO Question Checklist to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: My question is if the result (complex value) of any inverse function can be represented in degrees? 
Please look at the example inside the question. I get a result "90 - 297.5i" in DEG mode. Thanks!